# Change sorting order arrow in SSRS from ascending to descending

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportserver

I have Interactive sorting on each column in my report, but when i want to sort (first click on the sort arrow) i get by default ascending sorting. How can i change this so when i click interactive sorting to get by default descending order on all my columns.

For now i have just added interactive sorting on each column but by default sorting is ascending. 
[image]

Somehow i think this can be changed in rs config , but i don't know how.

Comment: Doesn't this work? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3599/interactive-sorting-for-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report/

Comment: No, i have the same as is described on that page. For every column i have interactive sorting(cannot chose if it's asc or desc) but as you can see on step 5, when we have up & down arrows when i click on arrows sort order is always by default asc. I want to change that so after step 5 to have first option desc order and when i click again asc order

Comment: Would it be okay to have the report generated in descending order?  That's to say by default, before any interactive sorting is clicked?  There's a fairly simple solution for that, if so.

Comment: I already have in my sql stored procedure Order By Field DESC, but i want to get from report server by default  Sort by DESC when i first click on arrow

Answer (score 2):

I've actually found multiple solutions that could be helpful, so I'll go ahead and submit as an answer and hopefully one of my suggestions will solve your issue.

As I mentioned in the comments, it is possible to sort the data on report generation if that is a suitable option for your report.  To do this, select the column that you wish to sort in descending order, right click to open the "Tablix Properties", switch to the "Sorting" tab, add the field that you want sorted, and switch the sort order to "Z-A".  This will sort the report initially in descending order.

If you prefer to leave the report sorted until a click on the interactive sorting, the simple solution to this is to change the expression for the interactive sort to `=Fields!Month.Value * -1`.  This will simply reverse the order that it sorts by, though the arrows do not change.  Additionally, I should note -- this only works on numeric fields.  You'll receive an error if attempting this with any text fields.

I found a segment of a book on advanced SSRS techniques that may be useful...  or may not.  It looks like the SSRS report renders as HTML and generates an `onclick` event.  The default image that is rendered is called `unsorted.gif` and changes to `sortAsc.gif` or `sortDesc.gif`.  It may be possible to insert some custom HTML that would sort correctly?  I'm not sure if the tags included are supported within SSRS, but it's potentially useful for your purposes.

[image]

Comment: I already tried that, even before you write here. But non of that works for me, that is good for sorting some column but my task is to change report server interactive arrow to be sort be desc

Comment: @user2171512 Seems like that will be a difficult solve, but I've added some additional detail to my answer that could be useful.

Comment: Steve-o169 this is what i want, but i don't know where i can find this HTML code

Comment: This could be useful?  Doesn't directly address the issue, but it seems to me that you'll need to use custom code to implement the arrows the way you need to.  I'm not sure the amount of work required is something I'm capable of figuring out, but I wish you luck.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930524/creating-custom-ssrs-handler-for-field-with-html

Answer (score 0):

Right click the row group month, select group properties, select sorting, click on order and select Z to A.

When report is first run it will be in descending order with available interactive sorting.

Comment: That is not what i want to change. I want to change SSRS Interactive sorting arrow to be descending by default when i click on the arrows